# PIG: how combine 2 relations into one

Tags: apache-pig

I have two relations:

```
DUMP A:
(1)
(4)
(2)

DUMP B:
(item12)
(item2)
(item32)
```

how can i combine these two into one that looks like:

```
(1, item12)
(4, item2)
(2, item32)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are implicitly doing a join on the line numbers but this is not valid anymore with Map Reduce.

Do you have the possibility to add a new column with the line number? Is you data huge?